# Async/await skipping rest of code in Task

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, skip

I have a function that i need to run when the page appears. This is the code below:

```
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            LeaveViewModel lvm = new LeaveViewModel();
            await lvm.FetchingAsync();
        }

        public ICommand LeaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () => await FetchingAsync());
            }
        }

        public async Task FetchingAsync()
        {

            await _apiServices.FetchLeave(this);
        }

        public async Task FetchLeave(LeaveViewModel lvm)
        {
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserID",App._username),
            };
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "somelink");
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(content);
            if (content == "[]")
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "No data recorded!", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LeaveViewModel>>(content);
                lvm.ViewList = new List<LeaveViewModel>(posts);
            }
        }
```

when I debug my code and reach

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

The debugger goes back to the FetchingAsync() function, completely skipping the rest of the code after var response.
When I run the code in a button instead of OnAppearing() and bind the button to Icommand, the whole code is processed perfectly. But I need the Data to be shown on page load and not when a button is clicked.
I read that it is because of async/await but I'm new to this and I don't understand what's wrong.
how do I achieve this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The debugger is following the control flow of the thread. You await something, so the thread is free to do something else. To which the debugger will jump you to. If you set another breakpoint after the statement, you should find it is getting hit.

Comment: This is fundamental to how `await` works. As noted in the previous comment, the debugger is showing you exactly what the program is in fact doing. Control won't return to the method until later. That's the whole point of `await`.